# SQL Query Returns Text (OR) "[B@XXXXXXXX" randomized string

Tags: mysql, sql, razorsql

I am querying a cell from a MySQL database table.  In that cell is a simple file path of a file.

```
SELECT
     Path
FROM
     webnative.path limit 1
```

Returns In RazorSQL: `/raid/DEMO/DEMO_CUSTOMER/JOBS`

*Same result every time I hit the query from RazorSQL…

Query from my other Esko machine I get: `[B@1b4476c1`

*Different result into Esko every time I hit the query

Must be some formatting thing?  I thought it was the fact the result had slashes but I did a replace in the query to replace the slashes with pipe characters, no dice, no difference.

I have double checked that both are using the same JDBC driver.

I tested all fields from same record return fine, just this data of this field are doing this.

Comment: What does SELECT
     Path
FROM
     webnative.path return?

Comment: Esko is a server box. It is the box that returns the different result.

Comment: SELECT Path FROM webnative.path Returns same as above but just way too many records.  I just need the first record that meets the criteria for another process to parse from there.

Comment: A guy is saying its stored in binary data Blob.  How can I write query witrh translation to convert on the fly?  Or can do a create function to do that. ?

Comment: Could you post the table definition for this table?

Comment: Is the path stored in a BLOB, or is it the file itself in the BLOB? I would have expected a path to be stored in a VARCHAR, or possibly in a text blob, not a binary blob.